# How can I change header text color on hover?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problems with my website header.
(website: "http://609.sint-rembert.be/leerling05/").
I want to make the header text color transparent but when the buttton "Ga naar de introductie" is pressed the nav balk should still pop up like it is doing now. The navbalk should be transparent when entering the site but when the button is pressed it should be doing the little animation like it is doing right now. The text-color shouldn't be transparent anymore when the button is pressed.  Can you guys help me out?

HTML:

```
<!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#Voorstelling"><img src="assets/img/elektroT.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Voorstelling">Voorstelling</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#eerst">Eerste contact</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Geschiedenis</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Team</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
#mainNav {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #212529;
}
#mainNav .navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fed136;
  border: 0;
}
#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  color: #fed136;
  font-family: "Montserrat", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#mainNav .navbar-brand img {
  height: 1.5rem;
}
#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-family: "Montserrat", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
}
#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active, #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fed136;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: padding-top 0.3s ease-in-out, padding-bottom 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand img {
    height: 2rem;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: #212529;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand svg,
#mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand img {
    height: 1.5rem;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "nav _bar_"?

Comment: You can't apply CSS with a button click unless you script it.

Comment: It looks like that site has some scroll libraries. You'll probably want to hook into that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Javascript to obtain the wanted result.

Add one line to the CSS:

```
#mainNav {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #212529;
  visibility: hidden; <!-- new line -->
}
```

Add this script to the bottom of your `body` tag, so just before the `</body>` of your page:

```
<script>

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (this.scrollY > 25) { // modify the number 25 if you want, this is the amount of scrolling towards the bottom
    toggleVisibility('visible');
  } else {
    toggleVisibility('hidden');
  }
}

function toggleVisibility(mode) {
  document.querySelector('#mainNav').style.visibility = mode;
}

document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary.btn-xl.text-uppercase.js-scroll-trigger').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    toggleVisibility('visible');
  }, 500); // 500 is the delay in milliseconds, adjust it a few times to get it right
});

</script>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks bro for the help! I appreciate the efford homie. It really means alot!

Comment: Thanks for the support but I got a new little problem... now when I click the button the navbar very shortly pops up when clicked before it actually should. http://609.sint-rembert.be/leerling05/

Comment: I added a delay to the javascript part. You can change the delay (in milliseconds) to get the timing right.